# What is the name of the Microsoft low-level, high speed runtime data capture program"

Tags: windows, runtime, low-level, debug-diagnostic-tool, highspeed

Microsoft has a tool that will capture SCADS of O/S low-level data while the O/S is running. We're talking memory backed by terabyte SSD. Although I've used it on a few occasions, I can't remember the name. Help.

I've just spent the last 3 hours search for the name and have failed miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!
It's the [Windows performance recorder]https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-performance-recorder/a1648e8c-50c7-4243-9f1d-4216385c7ff3?auth=1
It is part of the [Windows Performance Toolkit]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

Thanks to all that looked to help!.